# Select powerpoint slides and then build a presentation from it

Tags: 2010, development, powerpoint-services

I have a business unit that would like a document library that displays a series of pre-approved company Powerpoint slides. The user would then select the slides that want, click a button and a Powerpoint presentation would be built from that.

Does anything of this kind of nature exist at present? If not, what would be the best development approach for something like this?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't support this OOTB and I don't know of any 3rd party tools that do this but it should be fairly straightforward to do this in code.

[Here is an example of combining slides into a new presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316459/programmatically-combine-slides-from-multiple-presentations-into-a-single-presen)